# Managing subfolders in media library

Tags: wordpress, media

I'm working on a site for a client that uses a large number of images and we concluded that it's necessary to use subfolders within the media library, also being able to give these custom names (no auto-generated date based folders).
I guess it's possible to make some sort of function for this or use a plugin, but haven't found any existing solution.
What would you recommend?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a lot number of images, you can use [**FileBird – WordPress Media Library Folders**](https://wordpress.org/plugins/filebird/) to organize it. I'm currently using FileBird for all my client project.

Here is a screenshot so you can easy to understand how it works.

[image]

I'm using Pro version here https://codecanyon.net/item/media-folders-manager-for-wordpress/21715379 but if you need around 10 folders, free version is enough.

One more thing I love FileBird is the support team is very nice, they support fast and you can live chat with them on their FB fan page.

I hope it's useful for you.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, [there's a plugin for that](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-upload-dir/), but it's old (last updated in 2008) and seens to only accepts custom names based on wordpress variables. (`%year%`, `%month%`, etc).

In my opinion, you could use it and adapt to your needs with some coding.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I'll look into it.

I just don't get it - WHY is this not included in the core installation? It's essential for some sites.

Comment: Wordpress has a blog system background (nowadays, thanks to it's great structure, can be defined as a CMS). Adding "custom folders" is a complexity not needed for the majority of users - creating folders based on date is good for 90% of users who just want to upload their pictures. If you want more functionality, you can extend it through plugins. There are a lot of features we think should be incorporated to the core itself, but wouldn't be in Wordpress goals of simplicity and usefulness to it's platform in a whole.

Comment: I understand. But, wouldn't it be quite easy to implement a "create folder" function in the media library? That little extra would do a lot of good for certain types of sites.

Comment: What about creating a WordPress Pro? :) Then you can choose - Do I want to create a simplistic site (regular WordPress) or an advanced site (WordPress Pro).

Comment: Yes, it would be easy. But imagine implementing all sugestions people made to it's platform. Maybe in the future they are going to implement (like the new menu structure in 3.0), who knows? And creating two Wordpress versions would confuse users: which one should a user choose? Having just one version that works well out of the box with a plugin ecosystem is a better approach I think.

Comment: I'd have to disagree. I think it would be a very good solution if there were two different setups of WordPress. But as long as the dev team for WP decides that it should be a blogging tool I will understand if they choose not to include features such as this. But why stay a blogging tool?